Реализация сложения по модулю 2^32 и проблемы переполнения?
Есть нужда в реализации сложения по модулю 2^32.
Первым делом появилась идея - просто сложить два числа (uint32_t); после произойдет переполнение, но результатом останется 4 младших байта, что и должно быть результатом сложения по модулю 2^32.
Но не станет ли это случайно "undefined behavior"? Если да, то как можно реализовать такое сложение иным способом?

А зачем его реализовать? Оно и так в c++ происходит по модулю 2^32 (для 32-битных интов).

Сложение беззнаковых чисел не дает UB. Так что uint32_t — правильная идея. Смотрите тут раздел Overflows.

@VladD Спасибо, взял на заметку

@VladD Может опубликуете это как ответ? В принципе, как мне кажется, довольно исчерпывающе. Другим пользователям будет полезно.

Перед вычислением арифметического выражения целочисленные операнды подвергаются механизму integral promotion, или даже usual arithmetic conversions. Данные механизмы могут сменить тип операндов. К примеру в реализациях с 32-битным типом int выражение std::uint16_t(65535) * std::uint16_t(65535) вызывает неопределённое поведение, т.к. перед вычислением произведения операнды будут преобразованы в тип int, ...

...и дальше последует знаковое целочисленное переполнение. Что касается сложения двух операндов типа std::uint32_t то это безопасно если не во всех существующих реализациях, то в подавляющем большинстве. Но всё-таки стандарт стопроцентной гарантии не даёт. Возможно имеет смысл перестраховаться и убедиться, что операнд типа std::uint32_t после integral promotion всё ещё остаётся беззнаковым (для беззнаковых типов переполнение не вызывает UB). Примерно так: #include <type_traits> ... static_assert( std::is_unsigned<decltype(+std::uint32_t(1))>::value );.

Но даже так стоит проявлять осторожность и помнить, что, например, в реализациях с 32-битным int результат выражения (std::uint32_t)1 + 1LL имеет знаковый тип long long.

@wololo: проблема именно в 1LL. Если все операнды, включая литералы, имеют тип uint32_t, проблем не будет.

@wololo: А можно какой-то источник про переполнение std::uint16_t(65535) * std::uint16_t(65535)?

@VladD тот абзац, на который вы ссылаетесь в комментарии и ответе применяется уже после того, как все необходимые преобразования операндов были выполнены. Буквально предыдущий абзац. ... before any other action ..., the operand undergoes integral promotion. ... For the binary operators (except shifts), if the promoted operands have different types, usual arithmetic conversions are applied. Ну и красноречивее всего говорят вывод программы и предупреждение компилятора.

@wololo: То есть, нужен ещё static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(uint32_t));?

Лучше явным образом проверить, что после  integral promotion мы получим беззнаковый тип. Как проверить? Например, мы знаем, что тип результата унарного + имеет тип продвинутого (promotion) операнда. Если тип выражения +std::uint32_t(1) (получим с помощью decltype) беззнаковый (проверим с помощью std::is_unsigned), то соответственно тип std::uint32_t продвигается до некоторого беззнакового типа. Что это нам даёт? Теперь мы знаем, что унарные операторы +, -, ~, и битовые сдвиги, применённые к std::uint32_t действительно будут вычисляться в домене некоторого беззнакового типа.

@VladD Более того, если один из операндов std::uint32_t, и мы знаем, что другой операнд продвигается до беззнакового типа, то бинарные операторы +, -, *, /, %, |, &, ^ также будут вычисляться в домене некоторого беззнакового типа. Из этих соображений предложена моя версия static_assert в одном из предыдущих комментариев. Насчёт static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(uint32_t));? Если int 16-битный, long 40-битный, char32_t 32-битный, и тип uint32_t псевдоним для char32_t, то uint32_t продвигается до long со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

@wololo: Хм, и правда. Ума не приложу, нафига понадобилось при promotion-е менять беззнаковый тип на знаковый.

@wololo: Но может быть тогда лучше вариант взять unsigned long int и считать в нём? Ему promotion не грозит. А в конце результат обрезать до 32 бит.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Согласно документации, вычисления, проводимые над всеми беззнаковыми типами, выполняются по модулю 2ⁿ, где n — количество бит, и не приводя к неопределённому поведению (кроме деления на ноль, конечно) .
Таким образом, вам достаточно работать с типом uint32_t, как вы и предполагали.
А вот работа со знаковыми типами (например, int32_t) опаснее, так как переполнение в этом случае является неопределённым поведением.
Не забудьте даже литералы (наподобие 1) привести к типу uint32_t, иначе компилятор может вывести у результирующего выражения не тот тип, который вам нужен (например, знаковый).
Впрочем, некоторые компиляторы имеют ключи компиляции, которые заставляют знаковые типы подчиняться тем же правилам, что и беззнаковые. Например, у gcc есть опция -fwrapv. Но при этом ваш код перестанет быть переносимым.

Дополнение: обсуждение в комментариях убедило меня, что работа с uint32_t таки может в экзотических случаях приводить к неопределённому поведению. Для проверки неэкзотичности вашего случая вставьте такой вот assert:
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<decltype(+(uint32_t)0)>);

Для всех «обычных» систем этот assert проходит.
Что делать, если ваша система окажется экзотической?

Для MSVC, система будет неэкзотической.
Для GCC/Clang, используйте ключ -fwrapv, он предотвратит UB.
Если размер int на вашей системе больше 32 бит, считайте всё в unsigned int, в конце (один раз) отрежьте ненужные биты.
Если размер long на вашей системе 32 бит, считайте в unsigned long (но при этом ваша система должна быть неэкзотической)
Если размер int меньше 32 бит, а размер long больше, считайте в unsigned long, в конце (один раз) отрежьте ненужные биты.


Смотрите, что за экзотические случаи, и откуда они могут взяться. Дело в том, что C++ перед сложением приводит числовые типы размером меньше int к типу int или unsigned int, а символьные типы (например, char32_t) к типу int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int или unsigned long long int.
В нормальных системах uint32_t является алиасом на unsigned int или unsigned long int, и проблем не возникает. Но стандарт не запрещает делать глупости, и определить, например, uint32_t алиасом на char32_t, который имеет право быть приведён к int или там long int.
(Точные правила этой всей фантасмагории описаны в стандарте, глава 7.3.7.)
Да, а ещё на экзотической системе может не оказаться типа uint32_t.
Предлагаемый assert как раз и проверяет, что значения типа uint32_t ((uint32_t)0) после integral promotion (+(uint32_t)0) будут всё ещё иметь по крайней мере беззнаковый тип (std::is_unsigned_v<decltype(...)>).

Можно поподробнее, про какие "экзотические случаи" речь? Про int размером 64 бит? Это ж вроде не создаёт здесь UB?

@HolyBlackCat Если unsigned short 32-битный, int 40-битный с семью padding bits, и тип std::uint32_t псевдоним для unsigned short, то вычисление выражения UINT32_MAX + 1 приводит к знаковому целочисленному переполнению.

@wololo: а зачем такая экзотика? Не подойдёт 64-битный int? Для UB придётся сложить 3 числа по идее. Или умножить два.

@HolyBlackCat Для сложения может и не создаёт (хотя я не уверен, что будет в случае трёх слагаемых), а для умножения точно создаёт.

0x7FFF'FFFF умноженный на сам себя равно 0x3FFF'FFFF'0000'0001 - влезает в 64-битный int. Или я что-то не так считаю...

@HolyBlackCat: А вот 0xFFFF'FFFF умноженный на себя уже не влезает.

А, ну да, ступил.

@HolyBlackCat: В вопросе, конечно, только про сложение, но не хочется делать так, чтобы сложение работало, а умножение нет.

@wololo: А почему UINT32_MAX + 1 приводит к переполнению? Там же вроде результат влазит в 33 бита, а у нас в наличии 40.

static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<uint64_t>(a) + static_cast<uint64_t>(b)) выполнит сложение двух операндов типа uint32_t по модулю 232 без неопределённого поведения. У компилятора достаточно информации, чтобы на всех популярных процессорах выполнить сложение в одну ассемблерную инструкцию - приведения не приведут к вставке дополнительных инструкций в код.

Замедлять вычисления в несколько раз ради того, что никогда не произойдёт - сомнительная идея... Ну или рассчитывать, что компилятор сможет это оптимизировать...

@Qwertiy, получилось leal (%rdi,%rsi), %eax.

¿Зачем делать такую конструкцию по сравнению со сложением двух uint32_t?

@user7860670: К сожалению, это имеет смысл, потому что даже сложение беззнаковых чисел может приводить к UB. Посмотрите мой ответ за подробностями.
